# Eclipse, Error showing : Apache Tomcat - Port has been used already, How to get rid of this without Restarting the PC?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Usually,  the server gets stuck suddenly. After that server's start or stop option doesn't show up. 
And already port has been used error showing.
And PC need to be restarted to get rid of this.
There should be a way to stop this without restarting the PC.
If you guys have the solution please guide me.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried killing the process manually?

Answer (score 0):

Identify which program is using port to which "Apache Tomcat" is trying to connect.

Ither stop that process or use diffrent port for "Apache Tomcat".

Comment: Yes, using different port will solve this problem, But I have to set port each and every time this happens. And my question is after restarting the Machine problem getting solved and why can't solve this without restarting.

Answer (score 0):

use netstat from cmd get the pid related to the port no.
From task manager goto the process related to pid and kill it.